# SQL Server 2008 - Order grouped data by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to group `Customer` and `AlertName` to get how many alerts each customer has and after that I need to order results by `No_Alerts`. I'm using this SQL query:

```
SELECT Customer, AlertName, COUNT(AlertName) as No_Alerts
FROM Alerts
GROUP BY Customer, AlertName
ORDER BY Customer, No_Alerts DESC
```

Result is:

```
     Customer    AlertName    No_Alerts

----------------------------------
1    Cust1       Alert1       12
2    Cust1       Alert7        5
3    Cust1       Alert5        3
4    Cust2       Alert8       32
5    Cust2       Alert4       17
6    Cust2       Alert2        2
7    Cust3       Alert3      234
8    Cust3       Alert4       22
9    Cust3       Alert6        7
```

But how to get following result, so that data above is ordered by `No_Alerts`?

```
     Customer    AlertName    No_Alerts

----------------------------------
1    Cust3       Alert3       234
2    Cust3       Alert4        22
3    Cust3       Alert6         7 
4    Cust2       Alert8        32
5    Cust2       Alert4        17
6    Cust2       Alert2         2
7    Cust1       Alert1        12
8    Cust1       Alert7         5
9    Cust1       Alert5         3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to order by the total number (maximum number) of alerts for each customers.  You can do this by adding an additional column, using window functions, and sorting by that:

```
SELECT Customer, AlertName, COUNT(AlertName) as No_Alerts,
       SUM(COUNT(AltertName)) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) as TotalCustomerAlerts
FROM Alerts
GROUP BY Customer, AlertName
ORDER BY TotalCustomerAlerts DESC, Customer, No_Alerts DESC;
```

Note that the `order by` includes both the total and `Customer`.  This handles the situation where two customers have the same total.

If you really want the ordering by the max for the customer, use `MAX()` instead of `SUM()`.

If you don't want to see the extra column, use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: Thanks mate - MAX function this what I was looking for! Sorted! Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Vendor-specific solutions notwithstanding, it should be possible to nest your SELECTS.

The outer one has the ORDER BY, the inner one has all the rest :

`SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ... GROUP BY ...)
 ORDER BY ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another item onto your orderby:

```
SELECT Customer, AlertName, COUNT(AlertName) as No_Alerts
FROM Alerts
GROUP BY Customer, AlertName
ORDER BY Customer DESC, COUNT(AlertName) DESC
```

Not quite sure how "No_Alerts" worked in your order by before - if you wanted to order by a column alias you'd need to wrap it in an outer query as so:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Customer, AlertName, COUNT(AlertName) as No_Alerts
    FROM Alerts
    GROUP BY Customer, AlertName
) tableThing
ORDER BY Customer DESC, No_Alerts DESC
```

Comment: Beat me to answering with this exactly

Comment: While I understand what you are saying, the OPs requirements I feel are ambiguous - it could be interpreted as (Customer Name DESC, COUNT DESC) or your route.  I don't think it should be downvoted due to up for interpretation requirements... but oh well.